# repack vue3-module with repack for dummies

Tags: webpack, vuejs3, es6-modules

can you help me to repack module with webpack?
this module - [vue3-toastify](https://github.com/jerrywu001/vue3-toastify)

i use vue3 in ES-style, without compiling
module work well in ES-mode on dev, but my production didnt have any internet, so i find that webpack can help me get one js-file  to use it localy.

i try cook webpack like this

**app.js:**

```
var tto = (function () {
    var toast = require('vue3-toastify');
    return {
        moduleA : toast,
    }
})();

module.exports = tto;
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: './app.js',
  output: {
    filename: './bundle.js',
    library: 'myApp'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
  ]
};
```

after **npm run build** get bundle.js and use it

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../npm/dist/bundle.js"></script>`

in html use

`<button @click="myApp.toast()">test me</button>`

but no luck))
browser tell me

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toast')
```